# Is it safe to convert an escaped apostophe back to charcter on client side,

Tags: php, html

I have some text which is user input that is added to the webpage after it was sent to the server and escaped through htmlspecialchars. The text is not saved in a database and is displayed inside a p tag.

If the text contains an apostrophe then it's displayed on the webpage as `&apos;`, but I want it to display the correct ' character.

Is there a best practice for displaying this in a safe way??
I want to use htmlspecialchars because I like to escape everything which is processed on the server even if it's not added to a db.

I have achived what I want like this:
(ajax returns the escaped apostrophe as `&amp;apos;`)

```
var newdescr = response.descr.replace(/&amp;apos;/g, "\'");
```

Which works fine, but I'm worried it has security issues.

Comment: why not in principle just use `str_replace` on the HTML element? Replacing the HTML code for the apostraphe with the apostraphe character you want to display. Or even better, with the HTML code for the specific apostraphe character you want to display.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need to parse HTML entities back to plain text, much less manually. I have a gut feeling that you're fetching data with the wrong method.

Comment: I need them back to plain text because it's displayed on the webpage and I want it to look like this: now's, not this now&apos;s. Maybe this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Why encode it when you store it?

Comment: Thats a good question. Its because it's sent back with a block of html so  i escape it there and then receive from ajax and display it on the page. If I used htmlspecialchars as it's displayed after its returned through ajax would that display the character  not the entity??

Comment: Actually I can't use htmlspecialchars when it's displyed because it's added dynamically and the tag doesn't exist in the dom. Basically what I want to know is, is there any security issues with allowing the apostrophe character to be displayed if it's from user input?? Remembering that the text has still been escaped in php.

Comment: I probably didn't explain myself properly. Look at [this online example](http://jsbin.com/nucevumupe/edit?html,js,console)—no manual decoding needed. (BTW, is this a JavaScript question?)

Comment: Quite possibly, I think the issue is the way ajax returns the escaped apostophe like this &amp;apos; anyway I'll take a look at the link, but I think it should be fine converting to the apostrophe character way I showed in the op. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep adding <div id="foo">Patrick O&amp;apos;brian</div> to the code in your link replicates my problem. Thanks converting it the way I did in the op will be fine I reckon.